# What map-like std container performs the fewest copies during insert and erase?

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the implementations of map-like std container. By map-like, I mean something with a key/value pair. Which container(s) performs the fewest copies during insert and erase (or which is better at each if it's not the same)?

Comment: `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` are bot node based containers so they should behave the same for thenumber of copies created, which should be at most 1 copy (if not using emplace)

Comment: I mean, `std::map` is node-based. You won't get additional unexpected copies during insertions or removals. That doesn't necessarily make `std::map` better (pointer-chasing is costly)

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::unordered_map` internally uses buckets; wouldn't a rehash during insertion trigger potential copies? I always thought the internal nodes to those buckets were not stored indirectly.

Comment: std:map is sorted, though. Doesn't that imply that it's moving its data around?

Comment: @TheChemist `std::map` is a tree (typically, a red-black-tree). It only has to swap pointers around, it doesn't copy or move the `pair<const Key, Value>`s around

Comment: @Human-Compiler IIRC, the standard requires `unordered_map` to basically be implemented as a `std::vector<std::list<pair_t>>`, so rehashing should just be moving nodes of the lists around which wont move the actual objects themsleves.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for clarifying; I didn't actually realize the internal buckets were linked-lists. I always thought it was effectively `vector<vector<T>>`. TIL

Comment: @Human-Compiler Ah, interesting. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two standard map-like containers. `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`. There're also their multi-map variants, but I presume that those don't count as "map-like" for the purpose of this question.

Neither standard map like container performs any copies of elements during insert and move. They will perform operations, such as copies on their internal structure however.

`std::map` insert complexity is logarithmic unless you use a good hint in which case it's amortised constant time.  `std::map` erase complexity is constant with an iterator; otherwise logarithmic.  `std::unordered_map` insert and erase complexity is linear in worst case; constant on average.